# iOS storyboard memory management

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm new to iOS development and I have hit a snag, my app works fine, however there are memory issues. I have created multiple view controllers, with buttons. In Interface Builder I have created a modal segue between the button and the next view.

This all works great, however through using instruments, I can see that as you move along the app the memory is increasing, getting as high as 200mb, which seems to then cause a crash. I'm guessing it's because the app is loading the view controllers and their contents are staying in the memory of the device and are pileling up.

I have tried converting the project to ARC, this doesn't seem to have any effect, is there something obvious that I have missed?

Any help would be great :)

Thanks
Gary

Comment: Do you have any other code that may leak memory? Are you certain it's the ui?

Comment: Essentially I have the following, viewcontrollers:

1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5

When the user is moving along to the next viewcontroller the memory goes up, almost as if the previous assets are being stored in memory and not cleared. However I was under the impression that ARC took care of this?

Comment: I have tried Analyze, it states there are seven breakpoints, are these issues?